# Log4J with Pax-Logging display in GUI

Tags: java, javafx, log4j, osgi

I have an OSGI / Maven setup that uses Log4J and a Pax-Logging fragment with appender to name the file as desired, and then to log to file and console. I wanted to expose this fragment bundle as a service so that I can post the logs to a gui as well, but fragments cannot be started.

I am looking for a way to continue using log4j so that I don't have to feed the service into each bundle manually, but also to have access to the logs as they are written so I can write them to a GUI bundle as well as to a log file. Get some kind of hook into the log queue, or tail the logs into a new queue.

My only solution ideas so far are to read from the file as it's written, which is not ideal to say the least -- or to dump log4j and pass a bundle logging service in to each bundle that would use logging, then use the logging service bundle to write to file and GUI both. I'd like to avoid creating that dependency if possible.

This is Java 8, intelli-j

Answer (score 0):

You do not need fragment bundles for this. Simply install the pax-logging-api and pax-logging-log4j2 bundles. It includes integrations with all major logging front ends. Inside your classes you can use logging just like outside OSGi.

For the special appender for your UI you can create a service with interface org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.PaxAppender. This is automatically picked up by pax logging. For an example see the [karaf logging module](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/log/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/log/core/internal/LogServiceImpl.java).